# Mongoose ObjectID not working as parameter in a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to pass a Mongoose `ObjectID` to a function in an `onclick()` This is my code (shortened for ease of reading):

```
<a onclick="Like({{_id}}, {{likes}}, {{dislikes}});" class="btn btn-like"></a>

<p id="{{_id}}"> {{likes}} likes </p>

<script>
    function Like(id, likes, dislikes){
     alert("This function worked! Likes: " + likes);
     document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = likes + 1
    }
</script>
```

This does not work as expected. When I click the "Like" button, nothing happens. I did inspect the page element for the button, and it shows up as `onclick="Like(56ce7a3161714811003ae5f7, 1, 0);"`. This is what should show up.

As a side note, if I replace `{{id}}` with a number like 100, or any number, the function does run and alerts correctly. So my question becomes, are you not allowed to have numbers in a function parameter? Or is there a parameter length limit? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need edit:
`<a onclick="Like('{{_id}}', {{likes}}, {{dislikes}});" class="btn btn-like"></a>`

Because _id is string, so `Like(56e7df....)` is different `Like("56e7df...")`. 
With `Like(56e7df...)`, browser will compile `56e7df` as variable instead of ID string

Comment: Thank you so much!! I will accept your answer when I can in 8 minutes :)